# Haskell Lists in List

Tags: list, haskell

I'm very new on Haskell, and I'm trying the following:
To obtain `[1,2,3]` from `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`?

```
example :: [[a]] -> [a]
example [] = []
example [x:xs] = [x]
```

This example is returning `[1]` when input is `[[1,2,3]]` and if I add an other element in the main List, like `[[1,2,3],[3,4,5]]` then I have a Non-exhaustive pattern function.

Comment: It looks like you want the head here.

Comment: Actually I would like to get even the 4th element, so with an input like [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] using a function with "example [x:y:z] = [y]" instead of the one above

Comment: well `[x:y]` is *not* a list constructor, it is a composition of constructors. But I propose if you want different semantics, then you should update your question, or ask a new one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are quite close. In fact what you here want is some sort of "safe" head.

A list `[a]` has two constructors:

1. the empty list `[]`, you cover this in the first case; and
2. the "cons" `(x:xs)`.

It looks like you cover that in the second case, but in fact you do not: you put the pattern within *square* brackets. As a result, Haskell interprets your pattern as `[(x:xs)]`. So it thinks you match a *singleton* list (a list with one element), and that `x` is the head of the sublist, and `xs` the tail of the sublist.

In fact you want to cover `(x:xs)`. If we use this pattern, there is another problem: `x` is the head of the list, so it has type `[a]`. Therefore we should return `x`, not `[x]`, since in the latter case, we would wrap the sublist back in a list.

So a correct function is:

```
example :: [[a]] -> [a]
example [] = []
example (x:_) = x  -- round brackets, x instead of [x]
```

Note that since we are not interested in the tail here, we use an underscore `_`. If you compile with all warnings (`-Wall`, or more specific `-Wunused-matches`) Haskell will otherwise complain about the fact that you declare a variable that you do  not use.

## Generalizing to a `safeHead` function

We can generalize this to some sort of generic `safeHead :: b -> (a -> b) -> [a] -> b` function:

```
safeHead :: b -> (a -> b) -> [a] -> b
safeHead d _ [] = d
safeHead _ f (x:_) = f x
```

Here we thus pass three arguments to `safeHead`: a value (of type `b`) we should return in case the list is empty; a function to post-process the head (type `a -> b`), and the list to `process`. In that case the `example` is equivalent to:

```
example :: [[a]] -> [a]
example = safeHead [] id
```

But we can also return a `Maybe [a]` here:

```
example2 :: [a] -> Maybe a
example2 = safeHead Nothing Just
```

Comment: `safeHead f g = maybe f g . listToMaybe`